# How to select the max salary per department, including the employees that earn it

Tags: sql

Given a table `Employees`

```
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
| EMPNO | ENAME  |    JOB    | MGR  | HIREDATE  | SAL  | COMM | DEPTNO |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
|  7369 | SMITH  | CLERK     | 7902 | 17-Dec-80 |  800 |      |     20 |
|  7499 | ALLEN  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 20-Feb-81 | 1600 |  300 |     30 |
|  7521 | WARD   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 22-Feb-81 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
|  7566 | JONES  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 02-Apr-81 | 2975 |      |     20 |
|  7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 28-Sep-81 | 1250 | 1400 |     30 |
|  7698 | BLAKE  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 01-May-81 | 2850 |      |     30 |
|  7782 | CLARK  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 09-Jun-81 | 2450 |      |     10 |
|  7788 | SCOTT  | ANALYST   | 7566 | 19-Apr-87 | 3000 |      |     20 |
|  7839 | KING   | PRESIDENT | null | 17-Nov-81 | 5000 |      |     10 |
|  7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 08-Sep-81 | 1500 |    0 |     30 |
|  7876 | ADAMS  | CLERK     | 7788 | 23-May-87 | 1100 |      |     20 |
|  7900 | JAMES  | CLERK     | 7698 | 03-Dec-81 |  950 |      |     30 |
|  7902 | FORD   | ANALYST   | 7566 | 03-Dec-81 | 3000 |      |     20 |
|  7934 | MILLER | CLERK     | 7782 | 23-Jan-82 | 1300 |      |     10 |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+-----------+------+------+--------+
```

And another table `Departments`

```
+--------+------------+----------+
| DEPTNO |   DNAME    |   LOC    |
+--------+------------+----------+
|     10 | ACCOUNTING | NEW YORK |
|     20 | RESEARCH   | DALLAS   |
|     30 | SALES      | CHICAGO  |
|     40 | OPERATIONS | BOSTON   |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

How can I find the maximum salary of each department?

The output format line is:

```
DEPTNO,ENAME,DNAME,SAL,LOC
```

Comment: I assume the tag should be SQL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please tell me that these aren't actual people with actual salaries....

Comment: select e.ename, e.deptno, e.salary from employees e join (select deptno,max(salary) as m from employees group by deptno)  de on e.salary=de.m;

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subquery that will get the `max(salary)` for each department:

```
select de.deptno,
  e.ename,
  de.dname,
  e.sal,
  de.loc
from employees e
inner join
(
  select max(e.sal) MaxSalary, d.deptno, d.loc, d.dname
  from employees e
  inner join departments d
     on e.deptno = d.deptno
  group by d.deptno, d.loc, d.dname
) de
  on e.sal = de.MaxSalary
  and e.deptno = de.deptno
order by de.deptno
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78f2b/16).  You will notice that this returns 2 rows for `deptno=20` because there are two employees that have the same salary.

If you are using a database that has windowing functions, then you will want to use `dense_rank()` so then you will return all employees who have the maximum salary in each department:

```
select d.deptno, e.ename, d.dname, e.sal, d.loc
from 
(
  select e.ename,
    e.sal, 
    e.deptno,
    dense_rank() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) as salRank
  from employees e
) e 
inner join departments d
  on e.deptno = d.deptno
where salRank = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78f2b/22).

The result of both versions is:

```
| DEPTNO | ENAME |      DNAME |  SAL |      LOC |
-------------------------------------------------
|     10 |  KING | ACCOUNTING | 5000 | NEW YORK |
|     20 | SCOTT |   RESEARCH | 3000 |   DALLAS |
|     20 |  FORD |   RESEARCH | 3000 |   DALLAS |
|     30 | BLAKE |      SALES | 2850 |  CHICAGO |
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the maximum salary along with the employees, then use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select d.deptno, e.ename, d.dname, e.sal, d.loc
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) as seqnum
      from employees e
     ) e join
     departments d
     on e.deptno = d.deptno
where seqnum = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78f2b/4)